# PHP error using the preg_match function

Tags: php, regex, validation, email-validation

I'm was using PHP eregi function, but I get the notice that it is deprecated. Here's my code:

```
!eregi("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))
```

Therefore I am trying to replace the function with the preg_match, but seems that I am unable to get the correct pattern for the preg_match, as I get error with the following code:

```
!preg_match("^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$", trim($_POST['email']))
```

Here's the error I get from above code:

```
Warning: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found in
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: put / in the start and end of regex

Comment: You need to embrace regex code using a special char like: `~(\w+)~and flags go here`.

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate of cited question. It's about updating php and replacing eregi by preg_match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a delimiter at the beginning and end of your regex, commonly `/`:

```
!preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/", trim($_POST['email']))
```

Manual entry: [PCRE introduction](http://php.net/intro.pcre) / [delimiters](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters)

Answer (score 2):

You need to delimit your regular expression:

```
preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/",
            ^                                         ^
```

Answer (score 2):

`preg_match()` wants you to use a delimiter at the start or end of a regex string:

```
preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/", trim($_POST['email']))
```

The delimiter can be several characters, including `~`, `%`, `#`, `/`, `@`, etcetera. Notice that when you pick a delimiter, if that character is used inside the regular expression, it must be escaped with a backslash character (`\`). For example, using the regex

```
http://[0-9a-z]+\.com
```

with the combination of the delimiter `/`, will require you to escape every occurence of `/`:

```
/http:\/\/[0-9a-z]+\.com/
```

See the [PHP manual](http://php.net/regexp.reference.delimiters) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like,

```
!preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))
```

You must use a **delimiter** like **/**

Answer (score 1):

By the way, in order to validate an email address, you can use `filter_var` function as well.

```
$is_email_valid = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

Details: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php