# regex works at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but not with preg_match

Tags: php, regex

```
preg_match( '/[a-z1-9]{2,5}-\d(\.\d)?/', "example.com - ABC-1.0", $match);
```

This is working at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.  I get the expected matches there - it matches "ABC-1.0".  But not using preg_match.  The matches array is empty.

Comment: Use `$preg_match_all()`

Comment: [Check the documentation and examples for `preg_match()`.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP error using the preg_match function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114821)

Comment: I've edited my question.  I'm not getting an error.  I just get an empty array.

Comment: Why was my question voted down?

Comment: preg_match_all just gives me an array of 2 empty arrays.

Answer (score 3):

[You need to use delimiters when using PCRE functions](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).  You also need the regex to be case insensitive.

```
preg_match('/[a-z1-9]{2,5}-\d(\.\d)?/i'
```

Comment: @MichelleWilliamson `a` will not match `A` without case insensitivity (the `/i`)

Answer (score 0):

You can add case insensitivity inside the regex using a modifier group.
Also note that the group 1 is optional, so if it doesn't find a `.number` group 1 will be empty.

`/(?i)[a-z1-9]{2,5}-\d(\.\d)?/`

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `ABC` part should always match uppercase letters, you can make it explicit by using `[A-Z1-9]`

Better to be explicit than vague when it comes to regexes.